# primeng DataTable Header

Tags: angular, primeng

I am simply trying to Bold the column header in my table and it is taking far longer than I would like.  I've tried to override the ui-datatable-header and other attributes with no luck.  Now I am trying to use a template to do it.

```
 <p-column field="noticeType" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" [style]="
    {'overflow':'visible', 'font-weight':'bold'}"  filterPlaceholder="Search">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
              <th [style]="{'font-weight': '600'}">Notice Type</th>
        </ng-template>
```

The "Notice Type" label shows up with no problem but no styling is changed.  I've also tried just using the css file for the component to style the "th" with no luck.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try overriding the class `ui-column-title`  or `.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-thead>tr>th`  Overriding either with a `font-weight:900` works for me.